# Solve WebDriverException: missing ) after argument list error

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I have this code here to scroll to a part of the element which is a div box.

```
jse.executeScript("$('.//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/div/div/article/div[2]/ul').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 50)");
```

But I faced this error of **org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: missing ) after argument list**. How can I solve this?

Comment: I think your problem may be with the embedded single quotes `$('......id='react-root'...../ul')`

Comment: i removed the single quotes but then this **WebDriverException: expected expression, got '.'** error came up instead so i tried remove the dot as well and this happened **WebDriverException: expected expression, got end of script** @ScaryWombat

Comment: I don't think you should remove them, but maybe escape them?

Comment: i'm sorry but what do you mean by escaping them? do you mean like this? `$(\'//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/div/div/article/div[2]/ul\')`@ScaryWombat

Comment: something like that (maybe have to escape double quotes) I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Instead of single quotes, use double quotes by escaping them:

```
jse.executeScript("$(\".//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/div/div/article/div[2]/ul\")
   .animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 50)");
```